# Error while sending Video File from Java Spring Microservice to other Microservice on other port using Spring Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

Right now I have 2 Spring App.

App A will have a controller that will receive a video file ad Multipart file and sending the file to App B via rest template.

Some Code from App A that handle sending request to App B.

```
@RestController
public class AppAController {

@Autowired
private final AppBService service;

@PostMapping("/sendToB")
   public ResponseEntity<String> contoller(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
       String result = service.sendToB(file);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);

   }
}

@Service
public class AppBService {

public String sendToB(MultipartFile file) throws ResponseStatusException {
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
       MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
       body.add("file", file);
       HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
       String serverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8090/makeFrames";
       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
               serverUrl,
               HttpMethod.POST,
               requestEntity,
               String.class
       );
       if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
           throw new ResponseStatusException(response.getStatusCode(), response.getBody());
       }
       return response.getBody();
   }
}
```

And for App B, it will receive a video and extracting key frames from a video using JavaCV.

```
@RestController
public class ProcessorController {

@PostMapping("/makeFrames")
   public ResponseEntity<String> framesExtractorController(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
       try {
           File result = FramesExtractor.grabFrames(file);
           return new ResponseEntity<>(result.getAbsolutePath(), HttpStatus.OK);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
       }
   }
}

public class FramesExtractor {

   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FramesExtractor.class);

   private FramesExtractor() {
   }

   public static File grabFrames(MultipartFile video) throws IOException {
       LOG.info("Extracting Frames from the video " + video.getName());
       String directoryName = video.getOriginalFilename() + "-frames-result";
       directoryAssurance(directoryName);
       try (FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(video.getInputStream());
            Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter()) {
           frameGrabber.setImageWidth(480);
           frameGrabber.setImageHeight(360);
           frameGrabber.start();
           Frame frame;
           int i = 0;
           while ((frame = frameGrabber.grabKeyFrame()) != null) {
               BufferedImage bi = converter.getBufferedImage(frame);
               ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File(directoryName + "/" + String.format("%03d", i) + ".png"));
               i++;
           }
           frameGrabber.stop();
           LOG.info("Finish Extracting Frames");
           return new File(directoryName);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           LOG.error(e.getMessage());
           throw e;
       }
   }
}
```

Both app A and B have these properties set to their application.properties files.

```
server.port={There respective port}
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

And when i testing the application by using PostMan to send post request with video file in form-data body to App A /sendToB api i receive this error message.

```
"Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.FileDescriptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[\"inputStream\"]->java.io.FileInputStream[\"fd\"])"
```

So I want to ask what cause this problems and how I can fix it or sending video file to other Spring App running on other port properly.

Answer (score 1):

I edited my previous answer because you can actually get parameters from a response body in a POST with `@RequestParam` annotation.

I would use JSON as content type. This is my solution:

```
public String sendToB(MultipartFile file) throws ResponseStatusException {
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
       byte[] bytesFile = file.getBytes();
       String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytesFile);
       Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
       body.put("file", base64String);
       body.put("directoryName", file.getOriginalFilename());
       body.put("videoName", file.getName())
       HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
       String serverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8090/makeFrames";
       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
               serverUrl,
               HttpMethod.POST,
               requestEntity,
               String.class
       );
       if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
           throw new ResponseStatusException(response.getStatusCode(), response.getBody());
       }
       return response.getBody();
   }
```

For App B, the code would be:

```
@PostMapping("/makeFrames")
public ResponseEntity<String> framesExtractorController(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestBody) {
   try {
       String base64String = requestBody.get("file").toString();
       byte[] bytesFile = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
       InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesFile);
       String directoryName = requestBody.get("directoryName").toString();
       String videoName = requestBody.get("videoName").toString();
       File result = FramesExtractor.grabFrames(inputStream, directoryName, videoName);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(result.getAbsolutePath(), HttpStatus.OK);
   } catch (IOException e) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
   }
 }
}

public static File grabFrames(InputStream inputStream, String directoryName, String videoName) throws IOException {
   //Your code
}
```